# Null pointer Exception in JmsTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I have try to run simple spring jmstemplate example.Here goes for source code for sender,

```
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

public class MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate)
    {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
    public void sendMessage()
    {
        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session)
            {
                TextMessage message = null;
                try
                {
                    message = session.createTextMessage();
                    message.setStringProperty("text", "Hello World");
                }
                catch (JMSException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return message;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Here is config file for integrating spring with jmstemplate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd                        
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Spring AOP -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.test.QueuereceiverDB" />   

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="cache">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="QueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsSender" class="com.test.MessageSender">
        <property name="jmsTemplate"> <ref bean="QueueTemplate" />
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="Queue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate"> <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>queue/MyQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
         <property name="defaultDestination" ref="Queue" /> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmscontainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="Queue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

If i run the example below is the corresponding stacktrace

```
SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.MessageSender.sendMessage(MessageSender.java:30) [:]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149) [:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) [:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

After i have debug the code,i have found issue where it is,**jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {** While executing this line Null pointer will shown.

I think we need to initialize jmstemplate from xml file.But i dont know how to achieve this?
Please help me someone.

I have configured queue in the following file which will be placed in jboss/server/default/server folder
mdb-hornetq-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:hornetq"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd" >

    <queue name="MyQueue2" >
        <entry name="/queue/MyQueue" />
    </queue>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please show the definition of your jndi "queue/MyQueue". I believe the problem might be there. Are you sure the jndi is configured correctly ?

Comment: How do you get your messageSender? If you just new MessageSender() then spring won't inject anything and you have null in jms template. Could you add code, which get/creates messageSender?

Comment: Thanks @Arun.I have added the queue configuration file.please review.

Comment: Thanks @vadim.I am also same thought like how to call messageSender and where will call? I have tried sample app from this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-jms-activemq..they did not mention that.can you explain more about that?

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd that you have two JmsTemplate beans declared. I have a much simpler configuration that works. There are two JNDI names involved, one is the destination (queue) name, and the other is the connection factory name.

Let's say your queue is *MyQueue* and your connection factory is *MyCF*. To send messages, you need to declare just two spring beans:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="MyCF"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="MyQueue" /> 
</bean>
```

The source code in the sender class would then contain:

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

private void sendTextMessage(final String message)
    MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage(message);
        }
    };
    jmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
}
```

What is missing is the HornetQ configuration of que connection factory and the queue. That configuration defines the JNDI names. In my case, HornetQ runs embedded with JBoss Application Server. Therefore, I configured the connection factory and queue in the JBoss AS configuration (e.g., in the standalone.xml file). Here are the snippets:

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-local">
    <transaction mode="local"/>
    <connectors>
        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
        <entry name="java:/MyCF"/>
    </entries>
</pooled-connection-factory>

<jms-destinations>
    <jms-queue name="MyQueue">
        <entry name="java:jboss/queues/a/b/SomeQueue"/>
        <durable>true</durable>
    </jms-queue>
</jms-destinations>
```

I believe you're using HornetQ in standalone mode. It should be easy to map these settings to the factory and queue configuration there.